# Print numbers 5x5 with nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to write the code below in an easier way? The code:

```
lista = []

for i in range(5):
    lista.append([])    # >>> [[], [], [], [], []]

l25 = []
for i in range(1, 26):
    l25.append(str(i).zfill(2))

part = 5
k = 0
while k < len(lista):
    lista[k] = l25[part-5:part]
    k = k + 1
    part = part + 5

i = 0
while i < len(lista):
    print(*lista[i], sep="  ")
    i = i + 1
```

I want to use a nested list with several lists into.

The code above will print:

```
01  02  03  04  05
06  07  08  09  10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25
```

Answer (score 6):

You can build your grid with a list comprehension and then print it:

```
grid = [[str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(j, j + 5)] for j in range(1, 26, 5)]

for line in grid:
    print('  '.join(line))
```

**Output**

```
01  02  03  04  05
06  07  08  09  10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

counter = count(1)

lista = [[str(next(counter)).zfill(2) for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]

i = 0
while i < len(lista):
    print(*lista[i], sep="  ")
    i = i + 1
```

**Output**

```
01  02  03  04  05
06  07  08  09  10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25
```